# Excel file getting corrupted

Tags: excel, vba

When I save a file with macros in office 2019 it gets corrupted. If I recover it it will remove all listobjects, shapes, etc...
If I recover it in excel 2013 it will remove just validation lists.
Is there a way to trace opening and determine what is causing the problems?
I can also upload excel file if anyone is interested to take a look at in...

Edit:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/np02i4dhkrw9trh/SQLDB%20%E2%80%93%20ZA%20KALKULACIJE.xlsm?dl=0

In this file if you add validation list at Sheet1 to "Baza Podatkov" and then save and reopen it will corrupt the file.

Comment: Also pressing ctrl+R and going to the last tab and quickly clicking "pick" and pressing esc multiple times will crash excel... I assume new window is being generated at the same time as the last one is being removed from memory and thus crashes excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found that I was adding items to list without using comma or something. Still weird that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Corrupt Excel files is a common and known issue (when using the `xlsx` or `xlsm` format). Once a file was corrupted never trust Excel if it tells you it could be repaired. In most cases the file stays somehow corrupted (even if it tells you it was successfully repaired). **Don't trust this file anymore.** Start a new file, copy over the data and macros using copy/paste.

I recommend to save the files (especially if they contain big data) in the binary `xlsb` format. This is known to be much more staple than `xlsx` or `xlsm` and furthermore it produces much smaller files. Give it a try.

Comment: I saved it as xlsb, but it's still geting corrupted. Except now in recovery It doesn't remove all objects. It removes some formula... and I already did as you mentioned - copy data. Could it be corrupted tables? I noticed that there are some formulas embedded in tables that inject themselves when I add new row despite disabling AutoFillFormulasInLists at workbook open. I don't know where those formulas are hidden in listobject... is there a macro to remove all embedded formulas from table columns?

Comment: You must start a new file. Then copy/past *only values* (no formattings) format everything manually. If you copy with full format it might not work. If that doesn't work describe (in your original question) step by step what exactly you did to reproduce the error. • Make sure you are on the latest version (update your Office).